# Custom Settings for Custom List

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom

I created a custom list. This list has daily food. I added 30 days food in list. And when I want to show monthly foods, this list will show to me all items. When I want to see daily food, this list will show food of today. This list can show all items but can't show food of today.

How can i fix this?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be possible. You have to modify the view.

Default view is Allitems.aspx which show all items in list. If you want to show items that is created for today only the:

> Go to List settings>Views>Click All Items> In Filer Section> Select Created or Modified Column> Equal to> [Today]

By doing this, you will see only items that are created or modified today.

Alternatively, you can create new view from **List Settings** and set the settings that I mentioned above.

It will work like a charm!